# NServiceBus configuration interface question

Tags: nservicebus

In the NServiceBus interface, why are some things configured like this:

**NServiceBus.Configure.Instance**.Configurer.ConfigureComponent(ComponentCallModelEnum.Singleton);

And some things are configured like this:

**NServiceBus.Configure.With()**.DoNotAutoSubscribe();

What is the significance of "Instance" here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the first case you are configuring a specific component into the NSB container.  For instance you may want to load an NH ISessionFactory into the NSB container as a singleton object.  In the second case you are configuring NSB behaviour.  The "Instance" is simply a way to statically access the Configure class.  Using "With" forces certain configuration behaviour including the order in which things are configured.